# map indices with letters in clojure

Tags: dictionary, clojure, hashmap

I am trying to map indices of letters in a string `txt` in a hashmap, to do so I tried

```
(let[
indices (map #(hash-map (keyword %1) %2) txt (range (count txt)))]
```

but what I get is something like

```
({nil \V} {nil \a} {nil \d} {nil \e} {nil \r} {nil \space} {nil \s} {nil \a} {nil \i} {nil \d} {nil \:} {nil \space} {nil \N} {nil \o} {nil \,} {nil \space} {nil \I} {nil \space} {nil \a} {nil \m} {nil \space} {nil \y} {nil \o} {nil \u} {nil \r} {nil \space} {nil \f} {nil \a} {nil \t} {nil \h} {nil \e} {nil \r} {nil \!})
```

while what I want is

```
({:0 \V} {:1 \a} ....
```

Comment: just a clue: `(map-indexed hash-map "asdfh")` => ({0 \a} {1 \s} {2 \d} {3 \f} {4 \h})

Comment: and one more clue: `(zipmap (range) "aasjkb")` => {0 \a, 1 \a, 2 \s, 3 \j, 4 \k, 5 \b}

Comment: why do you want to convert the numbers into keywords?

Comment: Right, using keywords here is the problem. Numbers are great map keys, and keywords that aren't present as literals in your source file are usually silly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`keyword` returns `nil` for numeric arguments so you need to convert the indices into strings first:

```
(map #(hash-map (keyword (str %1)) %2)
  (range (count txt))
  txt)
```

or you can use `map-indexed`:

```
(map-indexed (fn [idx e] {(keyword (str idx)) e}) txt)
```